# Adding a scrollbar to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I am trying to add in a Vertical Scroll Bar to logConsole (which is a JTextArea). However, after following a number of guides on how to do this, I still cannot get the scrollbar to show in my GUI.

Please find the code below.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
class GUIFrame extends JFrame {
    static JTextArea logConsole = new JTextArea();
    static JTextField gameConsole;
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game Text Console - Cluedo Client v0.1");
    private static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private static ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
    private static JTextArea instruction = new JTextArea();

    static void createFrame(){

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        logConsole.setEditable(false);

        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        gameConsole = new JTextField(20); // LOG CONSOLE = Output uneditable
        JButton enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
        enterButton.setActionCommand("Enter");
        enterButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        gameConsole.setActionCommand("Enter");  //GAME CONSOLE = Input editable
        gameConsole.addActionListener(buttonListener);

        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) logConsole.getCaret();  // set update constantly on for logConsole
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

        logConsole.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( 1000,300));

        instruction.setOpaque(true);
        instruction.setText("Enter the commands here:");
        logConsole.setText("Previous events in Game: \n\n");

        JScrollPane jp = new JScrollPane(logConsole); //Add scrollbars.
        jp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        panel.add(instruction);
        panel.add(gameConsole);
        panel.add(enterButton);
        panel.add(logConsole);
        //frame.add(jp);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        panel.requestFocus();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Start by

Getting rid of `logConsole.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 100));` and replace `panel.add(logConsole);` with `panel.add(jp);`

## Why?

`setPreferredSize` will fix the size of the text area, preventing it from growing (or shrinking) as the text changes.  By default, the `JTextArea` will calculate it's `preferredSize` based on the `text` property

If you want to affect the "default scrollable viewport size" then you should make use of the `columns` and `rows` properties, which you can easily specify via the [`JTextArea(rows, columns)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea-int-int-) constructor. This provides a platform independent way to specify the desired viewable area of the `JTextArea`

By adding the `logConsole` to `panel` you first remove it from the `JScrollPane`, so it kind of defeats the purpose

I would recommend spending some time looking at [How to use scroll panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and the available examples

Comment: Worked as a charm! Thanks bro!